# When expressing ownership of something with apostrophe + s, is there a "full name" for it?

Tags: abbreviations

When saying "it's", that's an abbreviation of "it is" or "it has".

When expressing ownership using the same pattern, "something's", what's the "full name" of the " 's " expression?

Comment: Do you mean "possessive"?

Comment: The " 's " is variously known as "The genitive s", the possessive s, the possessive, apostrophe s, the Anglo-Saxon s, the Anglo-Saxon genitive s, and some other terms.. It never has been a true possessive as it marks an implied ***association*** of some sort between [noun1's] and [noun2] rather than a possession. This is because **possession** implies absolute control of something. Hence, the frequent unwillingness to use the apostrophe s as a suffix to inanimate objects, etc. e.g. "The door's key" or "The land that John rented is not John's land - it is possessed by the landlord."

Comment: You can find out the origin and history of *'s* on Wikipedia, which explains it better than I can https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive#History

Answer (score 1):

Possessive forms of nouns, pronouns, and noun phrases are not abbreviations of anything.

It doesn't matter whether it's *Peter's* or *those cats' suppers* or *yours* or *mine*. It's always its own thing. There is no unabbreviated version that would somehow be the "full name".

I suppose you could swap it around and have *the suppers of those cats*, but that's something altogether different.  Plus it doesn't always work: a *picture of me* and a *picture of mine* are two completely different things even though both are *my picture*.